# stellen vs hinstellen

Tags: verb, verb-usage

according to wiktionary:

**stellen:**

> senkrecht, mit den Füßen den Boden, einen bestimmten Platz oder
> Gegenstand berührend, in eine bestimmte oder übliche Position bringen

example:

```
Er stellte die Vase auf den Tisch.
```

**hinstellen**

> etwas an einem bestimmten Ort platzieren

example:

```
Sie stellt den Teller neben das Glas hin.
```

Still can't get a sense of when to use what. Why "to put on the table" and "to put near the glass" would assume different verbs? Can you give me more detailed explanation (more strict criteria) of what use when not only with examples

Comment: "Sie stellt den Teller neben das Glas hin." is bad German. To use "neben" and "hin" together is not used in general.

Comment: Let me take a wild guess based on the username, perhaps you're a Russian native speaker. In Russian you have a similar system where the prefix changes the meaning and where - with some exceptions - the rough meaning of the prefix is always the same. Consider: пойти, прийти, подойти ... из-, за-, над-, на- ... well, you probably know more about that than I 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to hardcore German. "hinstellen" is usually used in two contexts:

1. Something is to be placed to a specific location, this is 99% used together with direction specification "hier" or "dort". It is usually not used when the location is named.
2. Something is fallen or not yet standing, it is laying. Then I use
   this verb to express I fix this by standing up something.

The difference is subtle but is important to know. Some examples, please ask if the translation is unclear:

1. I stelle mich dort hin. I stelle die Tasse hier hin.
2. I stelle den Stuhl hin. Ich stelle mich hin.

Funny fact: the word "stellen" is special, there are a lot of compounds making it hard to everyone foreign but the deeper meaning is very interesting: hinstellen, aufstellen, abstellen, einstellen, klarstellen, kaltstellen.

Comment: Right, it's a versatile word which is often used metaphorically: *unter*stellen, unter*stellen,* überstellen, zustellen (2x), verstellen (2x), wegstellen, anstellen (2x), vorstellen (2x), Rückstellung, beistellen, durchstellen :-)

Answer (score 3):

*Hin-* implies a specific direction of an action, usually from the speaker away, possibly from the actor away.

I'd argue that it is most important in sentences that contain some form of *jmdm. etwas hinstellen*: that is like *to provide sth. to so.* In other sentences, it is more or less replaceable with *stellen*, as it is in the Wiktionary example (*Sie stellt den Teller neben das Glas* would also be possible).

Comment: It's a bit "dangerous" to translate the sense of _hinstellen_ with "provide", because there's also the other sense of _stellen_: _wir stellten ihnen die Ausrüstung_ ( = provide) vs. _wir stellten ihnen die Ausrüstung **hin**_. Maybe "to place something for someone" would be better.

Comment: @phipsgabler I agree, I actually meant _to provide **sth.** (to so.)_ which is closer to _jmdm. etw. hinstellen_, while _to provide **so.** (with sth.)_ would in fact be closer to *jmdm. etw. zur Verfügung stellen*.